# Displaying a lot of objects by means of Magical Record

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

The objective is to load ~20k entities on application load (in background thread). Then after load I want to show those in a `UITableView`. To this purpose with such big amount of objects I shall use `fetchedResultController` with batching set to like 100?

This is the way I'm trying to achieve it:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    for(int i = 0; i <20000; i++){
        Object *object = [Object MR_createInContext:localContext];
        object.number = i;
    }
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    [self finishedSaving];
}];
```

Then in `finishedSaving`

```
- (void)finishedSaving
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    self.fetchResultController = [Object MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES inContext:context];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I'm having UI freeze on that method. Any ideas to improve or fix?

Answer (score 0):

By default *Magical Record* has a batch size of 20 (see `kMagicalRecordDefaultBatchSize` within the source code).

So, with the following size, even if there a lot of objects to grab, the UI should not freeze. `NSFetchedResultsController` does the right job using a lazing loading mechanism for you. It grabs the first 20. If you scroll, it grabs other 20, and so on.

My guess (I don't know what *Magical Record* does) is that your saving code (the first snippet) is not running in a background thread or it is not running correctly. Could you provide the entire source code for it?

About the first snippet, do you need to run your task in the background when the app has enter the foreground? Just to be sure, using `begin...` and `end...` it does not mean to run a task in the background but just tells the system that you're in the middle of doing something (important for you) that would like to complete in the background if that's is ok.

**Update 1**

I investigated a bit on MR source code and here the results.

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    // This block runs in background thread
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    // This block runs in main thread
}];
```

So, does your `Object` only contain a `number` attribute?

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mffw03xujt90bxv/testLargeData.zip?dl=0
After calling fetching method you may notice UI freeze